# Javascript reduce array of object into one object with keys

Tags: javascript

Hello i am trying to repack array of objects and convert it into one object with specific keys. So here is array:

```
 const entryPenaltyGroups = [
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 8, penaltyTime: 16000 },
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 10, penaltyTime: 6000 }
 ]
```

Expected result should be:

```
{
   '8': {
     penaltyTime: 16000
   },
   '10': {
     penaltyTime: 6000
   }
}
```

I have tried something with **map()**, but not getting expected results.

```
   for (const entry of entryPenaltyGroups) {
        entry.map(x => [{
          [x.intervalId]: {
             penaltyTime: x.intervalId
          },
        }])
    }
```

Should i use **reduce()** instead maybe?

Comment: What's your expected outcome when two items have the same `intervalId` ?

Comment: Why `Object.keys()` with an array? Why `for...of...`? Why `.map()` in the `for...of...` loop? Why `.map()` for a single element? And why is there no `TypeError` in your question that will be thrown by calling `.map()` on an object (`entryPenaltyGroups[key].map(...)`)? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @malarres they don't have same intervalId 8 and 16 are

Comment: ok @VladimirŠtus then check my answer with reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the array into `[key, value]` pairs, and then use `Object.fromEntries` to convert the mapped array into a single object:

```
Object.fromEntries(entryPenaltyGroups.map(
    ({intervalId, penaltyTime}) => [intervalId, {penaltyTime}]
))
```

Alternatively:

```
Object.fromEntries(entryPenaltyGroups.map(
    entry => [entry.intervalId, {penaltyTime: entry.penaltyTime}]
))
```

If there are any duplicate keys, the last occurrence will be used in the resulting object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const entryPenaltyGroups = [
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 8, penaltyTime: 16000 },
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 10, penaltyTime: 6000 }
]
const formatted = {}
for(entry of entryPenaltyGroups){
      formatted[entry.intervalId] = {penaltyTime: entry.penaltyTime}
}
console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
entryPenaltyGroups.reduce((acc, el)=>((acc[el.intervalId] = el.penaltyTime),acc),{})
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `reduce`. This will override the item if they have the same `intervalId` , but OP commented that this is not a problem for them

```js
const entryPenaltyGroups = [
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 8, penaltyTime: 16000 },
      { entryId: 16, intervalId: 10, penaltyTime: 6000 }
 ]
 
 const result = entryPenaltyGroups.reduce( (acc,cur) => {
    acc[cur.intervalId] = {penaltyTime: cur.penaltyTime};
    return acc;
 }
 ,{})
 
 
 
 console.log(result)
```